# "Invalid config field backend model" magento how to find the missing part

Tags: php, linux, magento-1.7, magento

I have Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 installed, with several extensions. When installing a new theme, there are a few extensions included in that theme. (Ves Hitec with "magento_easy_tabs-1.1", "Mpycho_Jquery_Lightboxes-1.2.0", "Venustheme_ProductScroll-1.1.0")
It seems "Venustheme_ProductScroll-1.1.0" is causing the problem. When hit Ves_extension>productscroll>configuration, I'll get an "There has been an error processing your request" error (other menuoptions ok).On frontend home page I get "internal server error" - product pages ok.

I have searched for a almost 2 weeks, including trying to get in touch with the vendor/developer with no luck!!

I think this is some conflicts, and not so hard to solve, please lead me in the right direction.

Here is the error:

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:105:"Invalid config field backend model: venustheme_productscroll/system_config_backend_productscroll_checkQty";i:1;s:2024:"#0 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1/usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2/usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#4 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#5 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#6 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#7 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /usr/local/pem/vhosts/102089/webspace/httpdocs/magento/index.php(104): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:120:"/magento/index.php/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/venustheme_productscroll/key/0ab4cfadfe0b55f2cca35f94d7f388ed/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}  here
```

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/224717/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I have read this post earlier, checked my database for similar, but I do not know what exactly to look for... From the trace, can you/someone see more specific where to look/what to look for?

Comment: Does your default theme work (without the new theme)?

Comment: Yes, my default theme works(mobileshoppe), but when installing the new theme, it brakes down when installing one of it's extensions(productscroll). My other extensions are; "CallForPrice", "CustomShippingRate", "Lof Slideshow", "Ltib MassImportProductRelations", "OrganicInternet SimpleConfigurableProducts", "EasyTabs", "VladimirPopov WebForms".

Comment: I got same error. Did you fix it?